# WinSQL and Export with DB2

Tags: db2, winsql

I am trying to export a row to a DEL file using;

```
EXPORT TO ExportedFile.DEL OF DEL SELECT * From MyTable
```

However, when I execute the query I get this;

```
Error: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ExportedFile" was found following "EXPORT TO ".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

I understand that Export is not a supported command in WinSQL but is there a supported command?

Comment: Sorry, but what is winsql?

Comment: http://www.synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQL.jsp

Comment: Thanks, already googled :)

Answer (score 0):

`EXPORT` is a utility – not an SQL statement – and is handled by the DB2 command line processor.

IBM have made it possible to execute the `EXPORT` utility in an SQL statement by using the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure:

```
call sysproc.admin_cmd('export to /tmp/file.del of del select * from table')
```

Note that, unlike using the `EXPORT` utility directly on your machine with the DB2 client, this will write the file to the specified path on the database server.  You will have to retrieve the file from the server manually.

Answer (score 0):

WinSQL only passes its information to the back end databases via ODBC. Therefore, I'd like to add to @Ian Bjorhovde's answer and recommend that you enter that call into the query window for DB2 in WinSQL, namely:

call sysproc.admin_cmd('export to /tmp/file.del of del select * from table')